# Integral in three dimensions: how to proceed?

Tags: integration

I have never met integral in three dimensions, so I don't know how to proceed. I'm going to show you an example of my problem and if you can help me, I'll be so gratelful!

Let's consider a charged cylinder, its radius is equal to R and its height=2R. The center of lower basis is in the origin of the cartesian axes and its axis is parallel to z axis; we know the volumic density of charge: $\rho= 2az \epsilon$ where $a, \epsilon$ constant $>0$

We want to know the total charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You integrate the charge density over the volume.  In this case the charge density is uniform in $r, \theta$ so integrating over those two coordinates just gives the area of the circle.  So you have $\int_0^{2R}\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}2az\epsilon r d\theta dr dz$ where you integrate from the inside out.  The $r$ before the $d\theta$ comes from the volume element in cylindrical coordinates, just like it does in polar 2D.  For the inner integral you consider $r,z$ to be constants, so it just gives $2\pi$.  For the next, $z$ is constant, so it gives $R^2/2$ and we have $$\int_0^{2R}\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}2az\epsilon d\theta rdr dz=2\pi\int_0^{2R}\int_0^R2az\epsilon rdr dz=\pi R^2\int_0^{2R}2az\epsilon dz$$ and the last is just a 1D integral you should be able to do.  If the integrand depended on $r,\theta$ you would have to consider it when you do the inner integrals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can't I integer in dx dy dz?

Comment: You can integrate in any coordinate system you want, but working with cylinders makes cylindrical coordinates ideal (just as working with a round ball would make spherical coordinates ideal). Just think of polar coordinates in the plane along with $z$.

Comment: Sure you can integrate dx dy dz.  Your problem was set up in cylindrical coordinates, so I stayed there.  If you do the dx dy integrals first, you will again get $\pi R^2$ (note I fixed an error)

Comment: Please, be patient. I have always solved integrals in 1D and now I have to solve integrals in 3D but nobody explained to me them. I haven't understood why the second integral is between 0 and R. Why isn't it between -R and R? And, other question, if I integrate dx dy dz, I don't obtain $\pi$. Why? Many thanks

Comment: In polar coordinates, the $\theta$ integral takes you all the way around the pole, so you only need to integrate $r$ from $0$ to $R$ to get the whole circle.  To integrate a circle in dx dy, you need to get the limits right:  $\int_{-R}^R\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt {1-x^2}} dy dx$  This should give you $\pi R^2$ nicely

Comment: I'm trying to understand. The integral in $d\theta$ gives me the angle that is interesting for me, the integral in $r dr$ "limits" the region subtended by the angle and the integral in dz gives me the extension in the height. Is it corrct?

Comment: For the area element, you should think of it as a piece of an annulus $r d\theta \times dr$, comparable to the area element $dx \times dy$ in rectangular coordinates.  The limits need to be chosen to cover the area of interest.  That is the thought behind the limits in my rectangular integration of the circle last comment.